# Defining an Array that contains triplets in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to define an array that contains triplets such as 
Array a = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {5,6,7}};

How do I do this in Java? What data structure should I use?

Answer (score 5):

Create a class that implements the triplet, and then create an array of your new Triplet objects:

```
public class Triplet {
   private int first;
   private int second;
   private int third:

   public Triplet(int f, int s, int t) {
       first = f;
       second = s;
       third = t;
   }

/*** setters and getters defined here ****/

}
```

and then define the array of Triplet type:

```
Triplet[] tripletsArray = new Triplet[size];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a 2D array:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {5,6,7}};
```

Comment: But how can this store three elements? A 2D array can only store two elements at a time right?

Comment: The "D" stands for "dimension". In other words, a 2D array has two *dimensions*, or two *axes*. Each of the two axes can extend as far as memory permits.

Answer (score 2):

To do it with arrays you would define an Array of Arrays, such as:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{5,6,7}};
```

If you triplets represent some kind of object in your application, for a more object orientated approach, it might make sense to create a Class to hold your triplets, and then store them in a list.

```
public class Triplet {
    private int[] values = new int[3];
    public Triplet(int first, int second, int third) {
        values[0] = first;
        values[1] = second;
        values[2] = third;
    }
// add other methods here to access, update or operate on your values
}
```

Then you can store them as follows:

```
List<Triplet> triplets = new ArrayList<Triplet>();
triplets.add(new Triplet(1,2,3);
triplets.add(new Triplet(3,4,5);
triplets.add(new Triplet(5,6,7);
```

You can then take advantage of all the operations that Lists and Collections give you (inserting, removing, sorting, ...)